# Unable to change control panel theme

Tags: cp-themes

I installed the Nerdery control panel theme. Followed the instructions. The theme shows in the drop down but it doesn't stay selected after I save. Any ideas what could be happening? Tks!

Comment: Is it being set on a per user level? Member -> Control Panel Theme .

Comment: Just checked it. It's not.

Answer (score 1):

Is the theme being over written?

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#cp-theme

$config['cp_theme'] = 'default';

The nerdery directions tell you how to set this.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work. And I also tried different themes too.